# Why doesn't the range input heed changes in value?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a range input element with these min and max values:

```
<input type='range' min='0' max='9999999' id='mySlider'>
```

and then tried to change its value to no avail:

```
// This does not work as intended, at least in Chrome.
// It wrongly moves the slider to the beginning.
slider.value = 5000000;
```

Moving the slider to the very right side, however, works normally:

```
slider.value = 9999999;
```

Why doesn't the first snippet of code for moving the range input work?
[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7L87ck1x/)

Comment: That's weird, if you [increase the `max` by `1`](http://jsfiddle.net/7L87ck1x/1/) then it works fine.

Comment: That's actually really weird, it works with values like `3333333` etc. just not with all the zeros -> http://jsfiddle.net/7L87ck1x/4/

Comment: Woah, nice catch! Strange ...

Comment: If you start at 1-9 and add continue to add a digit, the anomaly begins at 5 digits (99999).

Comment: Here's an even stranger result -> http://jsfiddle.net/7L87ck1x/6/

Comment: But somehow this is okay -> http://jsfiddle.net/7L87ck1x/7/

Comment: Must be a bug in the way the numbers are parsed internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously bug. so I reported that.
[chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=463510),  [firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1138982)

It doesn't work in Chrome and in Firefox, but works as expected in IE11 (I still can't believe it)